# Como parar uma aplicação Quarkus?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

Não estou conseguindo parar uma aplicação Quarkus.

Após startar uma aplicação Quarkus (quarkus.io) mesmo após encerrá-la com Ctrl+C (pelo prompt de comando) ou clicando no botão de Stop do Eclipse, ela continua de pé. Exemplo: se ela sobe na porta 8080, mesmo após eu mandar parar a aplicação se eu digitar localhost:8080 no browser a aplicação continua respondendo. Outro exemplo: se ela possui um Schedule, ele tbm continua executando.

Já tentei com 3 projetos diferentes, com versões de java diferentes, eclipses diferentes e até máquinas diferentes. Sempre ocorre o mesmo problema.
Acredito que deve existir algum comando, parâmetro ou configuração que eu devo estar deixando de fazer.

Comment: Tentou aplicar no próprio ciclo de vida com `Quarkus.waitForExit()` ou `Quarkus.asyncExit();` dentro do método `public int run(String... args)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema normalmente acontece ao inicializar o quarkus pela uma IDE, normalmente utilizo o terminal para inicializar, e quando preciso debugar, realizo o debug remoto

mas se preferir continuar inicializando pela IDE, quando quiser fechar terá que realizar os seguintes comandos

LINUX

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o primeiro comando retornara o identificador do processo(PID) da aplicação rodando na porta informada. Já o seguindo mata a aplicação.

No windowns encontrei este passo a passo
https://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2010/12/como-fechar-um-programa-no-windows-sem-usar-o-gerenciador-de-tarefas.html
porem não pude testar

Comment: Não seria só resolver o no próprio ciclo de vida com `Quarkus.waitForExit()` ou `Quarkus.asyncExit();` dentro do método `public int run(String... args)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A maneira correta de parar uma aplicação é utilizando os comandos do docker.

Esses comandos devem ser executados no `bash (shell) [telinha preta dos hackers]`.

Os comandos foram testados em ambiente linux, caso haja algum erro de permissão na execução dos comandos, então tente novamente utilizando `sudo` na frente dos comandos. (Lembrando que não deve ser necessário utilizar o comando sudo para executar comandos docker, isso é um passo da configuração que ficou faltando).

Para listar os containers em execução:

```
docker ps
```

Saída:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
5981cbbb9f85        sebp/elk            "/usr/local/bin/star…"   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:5044->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, 9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9600/tcp   elk7
de6da8c2cd77        redis:alpine        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago          Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                                                                       redis
```

Após listar os containers em execução, basta parar os que estão em execução, para isso use o comando `docker stop`.

```
docker stop 5981cbbb9f85
```

Isso vai parar o container com este id, (liberando a porta que estava ocupada). Você pode verificar a porta que estava ocupada no comando (`docker ps`)[0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp].

Se você ver a saída do comando `docker ps` é com este comando que pode pegar o `id` do container em execução.